# how to set div on whole page using px

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to extend my div element to whole page but I dont want to set te scrollbars for page. I tired `$(window).width` and `$(document).width` but when i set this to my css the scrollbars appears. I cant add CSS `width: 100%` becouse other stuff in my application base on width in pixels not percents so it cant be done like this. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you post some HTML, there may be other factors effecting the width of your 'div element'

Comment: you can turn off the scroll bars by uding the css overflow:hidden;
Then re-enable just one of the two using overflow-x:auto; or overflow-y:auto;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I fugred it out.
I set in CSS `width: 100; height:100%` and then by JS I get dimensions in pixels by `$('#element').width()`

Answer (score 0):

Create a #mydiv that contains everything and then :

```
#mydiv { position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; overflow: hidden}
```

Should make it.